# Node.js post API is not working with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

I am trying to make a **post API using Node.js using MySQL database**, API is giving no response only throwing `error - code: 204`

I am inserting data using **Postman** -

```
    {
    
    "articleid":"1233wawdasyyyd4",
    "userid": "123uu"
}
```

**In MySQL table there are 4 fields.**

`id(unique and incrementing) articleid (varchar) userid (varchar) datetime (current timestamp)`

```
   var deletelog = (req, res) => {
   const articleid = req.body.articleid;
   const userid = req.body.userid;

 var sql = `INSERT INTO deletearticles_log  (articleid, userid)
   VALUES ('"+articleid+"', '"+userid+"')`;

connection.query(sql,[articleid, userid], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      res.send({
        "code":400,
        "failed":"error ocurred",
        "error": error
      })
    }else{
      if(results.length >0){
        res.send({
          "code":200,
          result : results
        });
      }
      else{
        res.send({
          "code":204,
          "success":"Record insertion Failed!"
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I don't figured out what's the issue in this code, I appreciate if you could help me, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There are parameters passed for the query `[articleid, userid]`, yet no parameters appear in the SQL. Replace the concatenation in the SQL with question marks.

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO deletearticles_log  (articleid, userid) VALUES (?, ?)`;
```

Comment: It is still giving `code-204 error` I have updated an info of postman please check